# Enemy Arms y Pos Glitches On Attack Pygame How To Fix?

Tags: python, pygame

[VIDEO](https://gyazo.com/99424dcfb60bc9561448acdef96d36c3) when ever my enemy hitbox collides with the player rect the y position seems to change I'm not sure why its changing and it looks glitchy and messy is there a way I could possibly fix this problem?

so first this line of code checks if hitting is True or Not if its true then if the player collides with the launch1.rec then start moving my boss arms towards the player

```
        if hitting:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(launch1.rect):
                if arms1.x < playerman.x  - 170:
                    arms1.x += playerman.speed
                if arms1.x > playerman.x - 190:
                    arms1.x -= playerman.speed
                arms1.y = math.cos(math.radians(arms1.time)) * 95
                arms1.time += 1
```

here if the player is not colliding with the launc1 hitbox  then keep the boss arms floating

```
                
        if not playerman.rect.colliderect(launch1.rect) and not attacks2 and not pausemove:
            arms1.y =  math.cos(math.radians(arms1.time)) * 95
            arms1.time += 1
```

next I checked if my hittings2 is true and the player collidest with the boss arms hitbox to tricker the attack then make attack1 = True

```
        if hittings2:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(arms1.sing1):
                 attack1 = True
```

if my attack1 is true then move my boss arms1 a little high and if its grader then 190 turn it off and make attack2 true which will make my boss arms move down  and turn of both hittings2 and hittings

```
        if attack1:
            hittings2 = False
            arms1.y = math.cos(math.radians(arms1.time3)) * 95
            arms1.time3 += 1
            if arms1.time3 >= 190:
                attack1 = False
                arms1.time3 = 0
                attacks2 = True
                hittings2 = False
                hitting = False
```

then here I checked if the attacks2 is true and its not colliding with the collidtest3 rects bottom then keep dropping it down

```
        if attacks2:
            if not arms1.rect.bottom > collidtest3.rect.bottom:
                arms1.y += math.cos(math.radians(arms1.time)) * 15
                arms1.time += 1
                if arms1.time >= 190:
                    arms1.time = 0
```

then these 2 block of lines of code below will restart my attacks

```
        if arms1.rect.colliderect(collidtest3.rect):
            pausemove = True
            attacks2 = False
            attack1 = False
```

```
        if pausemove:
            if attack1timer < 270:
                attack1timer += 1
                arms1.y -= 1
                hittings2 = False

            else:
                hitting = True
                hittings2 = True
                pausemove = False
                attack1timer = 0
                if attack1:
                    arms1.time = 0
```

all the logic that moves the enemy and attack the player in one line

```
        if hitting:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(launch1.rect):
                if arms1.x < playerman.x  - 170:
                    arms1.x += playerman.speed
                if arms1.x > playerman.x - 190:
                    arms1.x -= playerman.speed
                arms1.y = math.cos(math.radians(arms1.time)) * 95
                arms1.time += 1

                
        if not playerman.rect.colliderect(launch1.rect) and not attacks2 and not pausemove:
            arms1.y =  math.cos(math.radians(arms1.time)) * 95
            arms1.time += 1

        if hittings2:
            if playerman.rect.colliderect(arms1.sing1):
                 attack1 = True

            
        if attack1:
            hittings2 = False
            arms1.y = math.cos(math.radians(arms1.time3)) * 95
            arms1.time3 += 1
            if arms1.time3 >= 190:
                attack1 = False
                arms1.time3 = 0
                attacks2 = True
                hittings2 = False
                hitting = False 
                          
        if attacks2:
            if not arms1.rect.bottom > collidtest3.rect.bottom:
                arms1.y += math.cos(math.radians(arms1.time)) * 15
                arms1.time += 1
                if arms1.time >= 190:
                    arms1.time = 0
                
        if arms1.rect.colliderect(collidtest3.rect):
            pausemove = True
            attacks2 = False
            attack1 = False
            
        if pausemove:
            if attack1timer < 270:
                attack1timer += 1
                arms1.y -= 1
                hittings2 = False

            else:
                hitting = True
                hittings2 = True
                pausemove = False
                attack1timer = 0
                if attack1:
                    arms1.time = 0
```

Comment: What is the reason for `arms1.y += math.cos(math.radians(arms1.time)) * 15`? That doesn't seem to be correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to tell as you haven't explained what everything is.  Are the green bits that hang down the arms? If so, then I think the problem is here, where you are moving the arms1.y by cos(arms1.time). hitting seems to be set before any collision check is done, so I don't understand where that is set.

```
    if hitting:
        if playerman.rect.colliderect(launch1.rect):
            if arms1.x < playerman.x  - 170:
                arms1.x += playerman.speed
            if arms1.x > playerman.x - 190:
                arms1.x -= playerman.speed
            arms1.y = math.cos(math.radians(arms1.time)) * 95
            arms1.time += 1
```